# FB auth: extended permission on the first dialog

Tags: facebook, authentication

Some sites (klout.com is an example) when go to fb auth show the request for extended permission on the first dialog (not skipable) while I can only show them in a second dialog, the one the user can skips.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this just the new API and for some reasons klout.com is still on the old one? Or there's a way to ask for basic and extended permission on the same dialog as klout.com does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an App that was registered before facebook introduced their new auth dialog, it will have the old permission dialog box (on one screen).

If you are using a newly registered app it will use the "enhanced" dialog by default - you can change it under the advanced settings for your app.

Comment: How can I ask for extended permission on the first dialog? You said that I can change it under advanced setting for my app but I could not find it.

Comment: it now has it's own category on the left hand side under the "settings" menu, click on "auth dialog", then at the bottom you need to tick the "authenticated referrals" tick box and add your permissions in the boxes provided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already checked "authenticated referrals", but I still have 2 dialogs. First dialog asks for user permission (user_like) and the second dialog asks for extended permission (read_stream).

Comment: Yeah guys I am also facing the same problem!Does anybody has a solution for it?

Comment: I think that is just the standard way Facebook asks for permissions now - no way around it. I am reasonably sure you don't need to ask to permission to access user likes though...I think you can access them by default.